# Regular Expression: Match a string not immediately preceded by or followed by a alphanumeric character

Tags: regex

When searching for d

For example

- `" D"` = true
- `" D "` = true
- `"D"` = true
- `"[D!"` = true
- `"ad!"` = false
- `"sadness"` = false
- `"sa d!ness"` = true

Comment: Which regex engine are you targeting? Also, your title states the opposite of what your examples show. I guess you meant alphanumeric instead of non-alphanumeric?

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the title to be correct.

Comment: It's for use with ColdFusion, which is a web programming language programmed in Java.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
\bd\b
```

matches `d` only if it isn't adjacent to other alphanumerics.

Note that the definition of "alphanumeric" varies between regex engines. Most define them as the character set `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, but some also include non-ASCII letters/digits.

Comment: It seems that you've misprinted `\d` at the end if your regexp (should be `\b`)

Comment: That should be [dD], unless you're doing a case-insesenitive search

Answer (score 4):

You can use lookarounds:

```
(?<![A-Za-z0-9])[Dd](?![A-Za-z0-9])
```

Which means match `d` or `D` which is not preceded or followed by `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lF5oC7/1)